Call Protection For Libraries
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.27/contracts.html#call-protection-for-libraries
Can anybody explain this in simple way as I feel like the docs are very difficult understand sometime:
As mentioned in the introduction, if a library’s code is executed using a CALL instead of a DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE, it will revert unless a view or pure function is called.
The EVM does not provide a direct way for a contract to detect whether it was called using CALL or not, but a contract can use the ADDRESS opcode to find out “where” it is currently running. The generated code compares this address to the address used at construction time to determine the mode of calling.
More specifically, the runtime code of a library always starts with a push instruction, which is a zero of 20 bytes at compilation time. When the deploy code runs, this constant is replaced in memory by the current address and this modified code is stored in the contract. At runtime, this causes the deploy time address to be the first constant to be pushed onto the stack and the dispatcher code compares the current address against this constant for any non-view and non-pure function.
This means that the actual code stored on chain for a library is different from the code reported by the compiler as deployedBytecode.
